# Reactjs overwriting component when I try to create a component per item in my list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have an array of data resembling the following:

```
data = [{name: 'A', data: 1}, {name: 'B', data: 2}]
```

I also have code resembling the following:

```
function ReportComponent({ data }) {
  return data.map((datum) => (
    <Typography>
      {datum.name}: {datum.data}
    </Typography>
  ));
}
```

which is called in

```
function ReportBox({ component }) {
  const { data } = useFetchHook(component.urls)
  // data returns exactly as expected, an array of objects
  return (
    <Box>
      <Typography>
        {component.title}
      </Typography>
      {data !== null && <ReportComponent data={data} />}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

My issue is, when I run the application, I only get one output from my data (when I console.log(data) it returns the data I showed above), either
A: 1 OR B:2. I expect there to be both present in the component. Any advice?

---- Update ----
useFetch function

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useFetch(urls) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let i = urls.length - 1;
    const result = [];

    while (i >= 0) {
      const abortCont = new AbortController();
      console.log(`url ${i}`);
      console.log(urls[i]);
      fetch(urls[i], { signal: abortCont.signal }, { mode: 'cors' })
        .then((res) => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            console.log('something went wrong with the data fetch');
          }
          return res.json(); // why?
        })
        .then((data) => {
          result.push(data);
          setData(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
            console.log('aborted');
          } else {
            setError(err.message);
          }
        });
      i -= 1;
    }
  }, [urls]);
  // console.log(data);

  return { data, error };
}

export default useFetch;
```

--- Update DashBox ---

```
mport { Box, Grid, Container, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import ReportBox from './ReportBox';

function DashBox({ components }) {
  // console.log(components);
  return (
    <Grid
      item
      columns={5}
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
        alignItems: 'stretch',
        marginTop: '20px',
        marginLeft: '5px'
      }}
    >
      {components.map((component) => (
        <ReportBox component={component} />
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default DashBox;
```

--- Update Page ---

```
export default function Page() {
  const optionsFilter= [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C'
  ];
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('A');

  const componentsPage = [
    {
      title: 'One',
      urls: [
        `http://localhost:9000/page1?filter=${filter}`,
        `http://localhost:9000/page2?filter=${filter}`
      ]
    }
  ];

  const componentsPageGraphs = [
    {
      title: 'OneGraph',
      urls: [
        `http://localhost:9000/page1?filter=${filter}`,
        `http://localhost:9000/page2?filter=${filter}`
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Page title="Page">
      <Container>
        <Typography variant="h4" sx={{ mb: 5 }}>
          Page
        </Typography>
        <Container marginBottom="10px">
          <Typography marginLeft="5px" variant="h5">
            Filters
          </Typography>
          <Grid
            columns={5}
            sx={{
              display: 'flex',
              flexDirection: 'row',
              alignItems: 'stretch',
              marginTop: '10px',
              marginLeft: '5px',
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly'
            }}
          >
            <Grid item sx={{ pr: 5 }}>
              <DropDown
                options={optionsFilter}
                title="Filter Type"
                setData={setFilter}
                data={filter}
                key="one"
              />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
        <br />
        <Box
          container
          sx={{ border: 2 }}
          marginLeft="20px"
          pr="20px"
          pb="20px"
          pl="20px"
          width="100%"
        >
          <Typography variant="h3">Page Dashboard</Typography>
          <DashBox components={componentsPage} />
        </Box>
        <Grid container spacing={2} marginTop="20px">
          {componentsPageGraphs.map((component) => (
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography>{component.title}</Typography>
              <LineChart xtype="category" urls={component.urls} />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Page>
  );
}
```

---- Update again with the suggested fetch, unfortunately still overwriting ---

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const sameContents = (array1, array2) =>
  array1.length === array2.length && array1.every((value, index) => value === array2[index]);

function useFetch(urls) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const urlsRef = useRef(null);

  if (!urlsRef.current || !sameContents(urlsRef.current, urls)) {
    urlsRef.current = urls.slice();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const results = [];
    if (!urlsRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const { signal } = controller;

    Promise.all(
      urlsRef.current.map((url) => {
        fetch(url, { signal, mode: 'cors' })
          .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
              console.log('http issue');
            }
            return res.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            if (!signal.aborted) {
              results.push(data);
              setData(results);
              setError(null);
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (signal.aborted) {
              return;
            }
            setData(null);
            setError(error);
          });
        return () => {
          controller.abort();
        };
      })
    );
  }, [urlsRef.current]);
  return { data, error };
}

export default useFetch;
```

Stack Snippet:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

// Fake Typography component
const Typography = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;

// Fake Box component
const Box = ({children}) => <div>{children}</div>;

// Fake fetch hook
function useFetchHook(urls) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setData([
                {name: "One", data: "Data for 'One'"},
                {name: "Two", data: "Data for 'Two'"},
                {name: "Three", data: "Data for 'Three'"},
            ]);
        }, 500);
    }, []);
    return {data};
}

function ReportComponent({ data }) {
    return data.map((datum) => (
        <Typography>
            {datum.name}: {datum.data}
        </Typography>
    ));
}

function ReportBox({ component }) {
    const { data } = useFetchHook(component.urls)

    // data returns exactly as expected, an array of objects
    return (
        <Box>
            <Typography>
                {component.title}
            </Typography>
            {data !== null && <ReportComponent data={data} />}
        </Box>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<ReportBox component={{urls: [], title: "Example"}} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'd expect you to be getting a syntax error, `{data !== null <ReportComponent data={data} />}` is missing `&&` after `null`. Also, you open with `<Box>` but close with `</Grid>`. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I updated it - I will try to make a Stack Snippets, but the above code is pretty much what I have (barring that the ReportComponent is called in a page and rendered)

Comment: The code looked fine to me (other than that you need a `key` on the `Typography` elements returned by `ReportComponent`), so I copied and pasted it into a snippet and wrote up some placeholders/stand-ins for `Typography`, `Box`, and `useFetchHooik`. It works just fine. Please update the snippet to demonstrate the problem (and update the code in the question outside the snippet to match, or just remove it and untick the "Hide snippet by default" box).

Comment: So it will briefly appear all well, and then it will swap back to only having one item there. I know the data is present as expected as I log it to the console, but it will immediately after swap to having only one item in the component. I think the issue is coming from when I fetch my data, I update the value I will return with a useState. However, I do not return { data } until my while loop is completed. I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `return` in `ReportBox` and watch `data`. If you're only getting one item from `ReportComponent`, then `data` has only one item in it (after, apparently, having had more). Please also include the code for the `useFetchHook` function.

Comment: Adding the breakpoint now. Thank you so much, by the way!

Comment: I think the issue is pervasive since I have a chart that also takes in the data that should be two, briefly gives me two lines, before popping back to one). Occasionally both will appear, but then the data is not in sync (ie I swap the query to C and the graph gives me C but the box gives me B still).

Comment: How is `ReportBox` called? And why is there a `useEffect` in `useFetch` that has `urls` in its dependency array? That seems off.

Comment: Report box is called within another component, DashBox, that I am adding as an edit above. Dashbox is called in a page. I feed it an array of components which it passes each component to the reportBox, which then passes each url to the reportComponent.

I am not sure what you mean by the use Effect in useFetch. Is that not supposed to be how its used? I followed a tutorial to build the basic - would it be better not to have use effect and instead immediately go into my while loop?

Comment: That depends on how you want it to work, both can be valid if you expect `urls` to change and you want to update `data`/`error` when that happens.

Comment: What I want it to do is render the first time I load the page, and then every time the urls change, updating the data and error like you mentioned. What would you recommend?

Comment: Unfortunately, now the question is: What calls `DashBox` with `components`? The funcamental question is where is the `urls` array on the component coming from. It appears (now) to be from the parent of `DashBox`.

Comment: Haha understandable. The array is coming from Page, I will post that above as well, in which the inputs to the data come from a dropdown menu

Comment: Updated the page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Page` component creates a **new** `componentsPage` object with **new** `urls` arrays in the components **every time** it renders. Those new `urls` arrays are ultimately passed to `useFetch` (aka `useFetchHook`), where you have this structure:

```
function useFetch(urls) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // ...code that fetches and sets `data`/`error`...
    }, [urls]);
    // console.log(data);

    return { data, error };
}
```

That means that **every time the `urls` parameter changes value** (the old value isn't `===` the new value), **it will repeat the fetch and update `data` or `error`**.

There are various issues with the hook as well, the primary problem being that it does asynchronous work (a series of `fetch` calls) but doesn't check to be sure that the results its getting aren't outdated (because `urls` changed). More on that in a moment.

Since the `urls` arrays are recreated every time, `useFetch` does the fetches again every time, because no array is ever `===` any other array, even if they have the same contents:

```js
console.log(["1", "2", "3"] === ["1", "2", "3"]); // false
```

So you need to:

1. Have `useFetch` only start a new series of fetches when the URLs really change. If it's given a new array with the same contents, it shouldn't do a new set of fetches.
2. `useFetch` should abort the fetches that are in progress if it's about to get a new set of `urls`, and shouldn't use the previous results if that's happened.

You seem to have started on #2 by using an `AbortController`, but nothing every called its `abort` method, so it didn't do anything.

Here's a version of `useFetch` that handles both of those things, see the comments:

```
const sameContents = (array1, array2) => {
    return array1.length === array2.length &&
           array1.every((value, index) => value === array2[index]);
};

function useFetch(urls) {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const urlsRef = useRef(null);               // A place to keep the URLs we're handling

    if (!urlsRef.current ||                     // Mounting, or
        !sameContents(urlsRef.current, urls)    // Called after mount with *different* URLs
       ) {
        // Remember these URLs
        urlsRef.current = urls.slice();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!urlsRef.current) {
            // Nothing to do
            return;
        }
        // Use the same controller and signal for all the fetches
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const {signal} = controller;
        // Use `Promise.all` to wait for all the fetches to complete (or one
        // of them to fail) before setting `data`.
        Promise.all(urlsRef.current.map(url =>
            // Note: You had `{ mode: "cors" }` on its own as a third argument,
            // but it should have been part of the second argument (`fetch`
            // only takes two).
            fetch(url, {signal, mode: "cors"})
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    // HTTP error
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
                }
                // HTTP okay, read the body of the response and parse it
                return res.json();
            })
        ))
        .then(data => {
            // Got all the data. If this set of results isn't out of date,
            // set it and clear any previous error
            if (!signal.aborted) {
                setData(data);
                setError(null);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // Do nothing if these results are out of date
            if (signal.aborted) {
                return;
            }
            // Clear data, set error
            setData(null);
            setError(error);
        });
        // Return a cleanup callback to abort the set of fetches when we get
        // new URLs.
        return () => {
            controller.abort();
        };
    }, [urlsRef.current]); // <=== Use this instead of `urls`

    return { data, error };
}
```

That's a **sketch**, I won't be surprised if you need to make small tweaks to it, but it should get you going the right way.

Comment: I normally have a firm "don't post and run" policy, but it's dinner time and I'm told it's on the table, so... :-)

Comment: I beyond appreciate this. And don't worry about dinner, that will give me some time to look it over. Have a good dinner, and thank you again!

Comment: Question - what is the urlsRef.current? I am not familiar with this concept. Hope dinner was lovely!

Comment: @ChristinaStebbins - Glad to help. `ursRef.current` is the current value of the [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#refs). More about the hook [hre](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Comment: Hiya, T.J.!
I implemented your suggestion - It does not seem to have fixed the issue where my two data particles are not showing up.  I am uploading my implementation. Hopefully can dig out the issue with some more work! (your implementation works, I still seem to be fetching data twice in a single render of the page). Perhaps the issue is that I am appending the data to a result const to use the data all encompassed in one location. Let me know if you have any thoughts, but thank you for the help!